# ¿Como mejorar el stretch_blit de Allegro 4?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, allegro, mingw

tengo una duda para los que estén familiarizados con la librería Allegro de C++. Estoy usando la versión 4.4.2, y mi programa usa la función stretch_blit para dibujar en la pantalla un bitmap de gran tamaño, achicándolo para que encaje en las dimensiones de la pantalla. El problema es que este redimensionado, aunque en mi caso mantengo la misma relación de aspecto, es de muy poca calidad, las imágenes quedan como torcidas y no hay un suavizado como en otros programas como Photoshop. Me preguntaba si había alguna librería de Allegro que ayudara a mejorar esto, tal vez con antialiasing o algo que ayudara a que la imagen redimensionada quedara mejor. Agradecería sus sugerencias

EDITO: buscando en el sitio oficial, encontré algunas librerías de antialiasing para Allegro 4, aunque parece que esta funcionalidad viene incluida con Allegro 5 por defecto. Hasta ahora, el único link que me ha funcionado es [este](https://bitblaze.com/allegro/aastr2-0.71.tar.bz), pero lo descargué y trae solo el código fuente y algunos ejemplos, y en [la página de descarga](https://www.allegro.cc/resource/Libraries/Graphics/AASTR2) me dicen que compile los códigos fuente y linkee al programa los archivos .o o .obj resultantes, y ahora mi duda es qué tengo que hacer ahí exactamente, porque en mi Dev-C++ estos archivos dan error al compilar, además de que aun si lo hicieran, se generaría un .exe al final del proceso (que según tengo entendido, es de compilación+linkado...) ¿Pero qué hago para compilar esto bien? Agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he resuelto. He tenido que aprender por mí mismo, pero tampoco era tan difícil (a decir verdad, que no lo supiera hacer demuestra lo noob que soy xd)
Como uso Dev-C++, solo tuve que crear un nuevo proyecto de tipo Static Library. Entonces añadí los códigos fuente listados en [la página de descarga](https://www.allegro.cc/resource/Libraries/Graphics/AASTR2) y compilé, y se produjeron los archivos que necesitaba.
Esto fue lo que tuve que hacer en mi entorno con el mingw del Dev-C++. Pero para una explicación más detallada, para el que no use Dev-C++, hay que compilarlo manualmente con los programas de la carpeta bin del compilador.
Primero, compilar los códigos fuente con el g++, especificando los destinos como .o. Luego, ejecutar el programa
"ar.exe" con los parámetros:

```
ar r <nombre de la libreria> <archivos .o>
```

y despues ejecutar ranlib pasándole de parámetros el nombre de la librería .a producida por ar.exe. (Recomiendo ponerle a la librería un nombre que empiece por "lib", como "libaastr.a", porque solo así me funcionó a mí)
Luego, pasamos este archivo .a la carpeta lib de nuestro compilador, y el archivo de cabecera, en este caso aastr.h, a la carpeta includes. Luego en nuestro programa, incluimos este header y lo linkeamos a -laastr (por eso su nombre debe empezar por lib) y ya nos debe funcionar.
En este caso, la documentación de la librería para utilizar el antialiasing se encuentra en el propio header aastr.h. Lo he probado, y funciona!